# How to read/store client created data on the server side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

i have one conceptual problem in my project:

Following the tutorial "updating related data with ef in asp.net mvc", i have a similar problem. I want to create a student (name + id) with related data (its a comment only) on the create student page. For one student can be more than one comment. The comments are added to a table below the students data in the create student page. My Goal is, that the comments are only saved when the student is created. The comments can be added/deleted and modified before the student is created via a button click.

At the moment, i add the comments directly to the html table with javascript/jquery and try to read the form data in the controller. I want to know if there is a better way to manipulate the comments data on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the best solution in my opinion is to use javascript/jquery to dynamically add more rows for comments. When you hit the *"Create"* button, form data is automatically serialized and sent to server.
Your controller should have a View Model containing properties for all student data + `List<string>` (or whatever collection you want) for comments. If that's how it works in your system, it's good. However, if you read the form data using Request.Form (instead of model binding), you should correct that (it's not technically wrong, but it's bad practice)